# php script execute twice with php curl

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase push notification service in my android app and php script. I want to sent notification after every insert to mysql DB. I am facing problem, when I call my custom method named sendNotifications() it execute the php script again and insert in DB execute twice so that notifications also send twice. Here is the code.. 
From here i call insert to DB and after that i call sendNotifications method

```
if($_POST['action']  == $news::$INSERT)
    {
            $isInserted = $news->insert($_POST);
            if($isInserted){            
                deliverResponse(200,'Success..',true,NULL);
                $message = $news->selectLastInserted();
                if(count($message) > 0)
                {
                    require_once('fcm_notify.php');
                    $obj = new NotifiyUsers();
                    $obj->sendNotifications($message);
                }
            }
            else
                deliverResponse(200,'Failed...',false,NULL);

    }
```

and here is the my sendNotification method

```
class NotifiyUsers{
function sendNotifications($message)
{
    //getting tokens from users table to send notification
    $users = new FMCUser();
    $tokens = $users->selectTokens();
    if(count($users)<0) // if no user register
        return;
    ////
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                    'data' => $message,
                    );
    $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key ='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
    // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }   
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);            
        return $result;
}
}
```