# How to send Firebase Notifications from website to Android

Tags: android, notifications, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the best way to send push notification to all of my users in Android. I have Firebase and now I'm using their backend website, but I want to do it by php or something.

Comment: That is known as [sending downstream messages in Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream) terminology. I suggest you read a bit more of the documentation, and related questions here (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038950/php-script-execute-twice-with-php-curl) or likely others in [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging+php)). With those you should be able to get somewhere. As it stands this question is a bit broad.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen All what I need is some script that when I publish post in Wordpress, automatically send push notification to all of my Android users. Like Notification Firebase backend website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to send notifications to all users except using **Firebase Console**, see image:

[image: Firebase Console]

However if you are planning to do it by your own curl requests, then you should have planned it earlier. To do so you have to save the registration tokens of all users on your server. As of now, Firebase neither provide you the list of all registered tokens nor a way to send a push message to all users.

Curl request to send notification to multiple users, it will be delivered directly in onMessageReceived() method.

### HTTP POST Request

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
>
> Content-Type:application/json
>
> Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "registration_ids" : [
    "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "bk3RNH0adsf:CI2k_HadfasdoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
    ]
}
```